d3 tick format to change unicode to HYPHEN-MINUS (U+002D) for negative values
I realized d3.js returns negative values on xAxis with MINUS unicode (U+2212), but I need it as HYPHEN-MINUS unicode(U+002D). How can I do that within the code below;


    const locale = d3.formatLocale({
      minus: '\u002D',
    })

 const xAxisGroup = d3.select(ref.current)

    xAxisGroup.selectAll('g').remove()

    xAxisGroup
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(0,${DEFAULTS.margin.top})`)
      .call(
        d3
          .axisTop(x)
          .tickFormat(locale)
          .ticks(DEFAULTS.width / 80),
      )



But I am not getting what I expected when I add tickFormat(locale) line. I am doing it wrong. Can someone help me about how to apply the format to my xAxis ticks.

d3.formatLocale is not a formatter; you need something like d3.formatLocale(...).format('.2f'). Or you can use d3.formatDefaultLocale, which both creates a locale and sets the defaults of all subsequent calls to d3.format.
